# Perl MySQL programming

Tags: mysql, perl, orm

I want to write few process intensive back-end scripts for a web application using Perl and MySQL.

I will be frequently using embedded SQL in my scripts. Can anyone suggest a structured way to do that. I feel it will take lot of time to create generic classes for tables, if I have to use tables as classes and create functions like Add, Update or find to run Insert, update or select statements. Also such code itself will be quite vast than my actual business code. On the other side I do not want to use unstructured queries spread allover the code.

Are there any inbuilt class libraries to take care of my needs.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have tried to edit my question. I hope the question is generic enough now. If not, please suggest, so I can update again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class) is the best in class for an [object-relational mapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) in Perl.  It will take care of all the SQL to add, update, delete and search and will do it efficiently.  You tell it the tables, columns, keys and relationships.  [DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader) can even do that part for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solves my purpose and gives me a technical name for my needs for future queries.